# Parse string to valid php object

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I'm receiving a string like this:

```
{
    key1 = "some value";
    key2 = "some value";
    key3 = "some value";
    key4 = 1235678;
}
```

and I need to parse it so it becomes a valid php object or array. I suppose Regex is the way to go  but I'm really bad at it.

Comment: Where is this string coming from?  Maybe you can get JSON instead, and then use `json_decode`?

Comment: I was supposed to receive a JSON string but apparently my coworker doesnt know the meaning of JSON XD, and I there is no time to ask him to change it.

Comment: Is your string like this: _{key1 = "some value"; key2 = "some value"; key3 = "some value"; key4 = 1235678;}_? And you want to place what's inside the "" into an array?

Comment: kill your coworker isn't an option? I mean he nearly did JSON, just replacing the `=` with `:` and the `;` with `,` :)

Comment: Where are you getting that string? Is it possible to get it into a format that can already be parsed by PHP? (You could hack that format exactly into JSON by replacing ' = ' with ':' and ';' by ',', but you would need a regex to do it right and make sure you weren't removing characters inside the string). If you CAN get it in json, it will be easy.

Comment: no, I cant get it in JSON for the moment.

Comment: If your coworker has invented a new format, he should have the courtesy to include libraries to parse it.  +1 for "kill your coworker".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .. Crazy But it works ( I would recommend JSON anyway )

```
    $string = '{
        key1 = "some value";
        key2 = "some value";
        key3 = "some value";
        key4 = 1235678;
    }' ;



    var_dump(parseString($string));

    function parseString($string)
    {
        $output = array();
        $string = str_replace(array("{","}"), "", $string);
        $string = explode(";",$string) ;

        foreach($string as $values)
        {
            $values = trim($values);

            if(strpos($values, "="))
            {
                list($key,$value) = explode("=",$values);
                $value = trim($value) ;
                $value = trim($value,"\"") ;
                $key = trim($key);
                $output[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $output ;
    }
```

Result

```
    array
    'key1 ' => string 'some value' (length=10)
    'key2 ' => string 'some value' (length=10)
    'key3 ' => string 'some value' (length=10)
    'key4 ' => string '1235678' (length=7)
```

Comment: I'll use this for the moment, it's easier than the token_get_all thing and works fine so far. Either way I still prefer the 'kill your coworker' option

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to parse it yourself. Fortunately you can at least break it into tokens first with [token_get_all](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php):

```
$str = '{
    key1 = "some= value1";
}';
print_r(token_get_all('<?php ' . $str . ' ?>'));

/* output:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 368
            [1] =>  1
        )

    [1] => {
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 371
            [1] => 

            [2] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 307
            [1] => key1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 371
            [1] =>  
            [2] => 2
        )

    [5] => =
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 371
            [1] =>  
            [2] => 2
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 315
            [1] => "some= value1"
            [2] => 2
        )

    [8] => ;
    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 371
            [1] => 

            [2] => 2
        )

    [10] => }
    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 371
            [1] =>  
            [2] => 3
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 370
            [1] => ?>
            [2] => 3
        )

)

*/
```

You can then iterate over the returned array looking for `=` and `;` to find assignments and end of statements. Keep in mind that it will parse out tokens that are to be interpolated, e.g., `key1 = "some $value"` will parse out `$value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$strA = array_filter(explode(";",YourString));
foreach($strA as $combineValue){
   $cV = array_filter(explode("=",combineValue));
    echo $cv[0].'--'.$cv[1];
}
```

Not having resources right now to test the snippet. But i think it should help.

This is the validate JSON conversion of your response (may help you) it would be good  if u can get json respose:

```
{
"key1": "some value",
"key2": "some value",
"key3": "some value",
"key4": 1235678
}
```